# Strange Kotlin behaviour using Data Classes in Maps

Tags: kotlin, hashmap, hashcode, data-class

I'm new to Kotlin and I'm trying to understand it, I've just written a simple example that shows how using data classes with maps is a bit tricky, because it seems to me that data classes have a strange behaviour. **By default, they define hashCode() based on every property of the class. But they don't define a default equals() method**.
This caused to me a lot of confusion because I created a HashMap with a Data Class as a key, but I didn't override hashCode() and equals(). My data class has a MutableList member. When I put an element in the map, I retrieved it using map.get(dataObject) as long as I didn't add an element to the MutableList. After that, even if the data object was still the same, and I found it using map.keys (map.keys.indexOf(dataObject) works), map.get(dataObject) failed, due to the hashCode().

I can fix it using a normal class or adding hashCode() and equals(), removing the MutableList from hashCode(), but I'm wondering if, due to the default behaviour, overriding hashCode() and equals() should be "mandatory" with data classes because otherwise using them with Maps can lead to errors.

Is there something else I can do to avoid this problem?

```
    package cards
    
    data class Player(val name: String, var cards: MutableList<Card>) {
        constructor(name: String): this(name, mutableListOf())
    
    //I don't need to define equals, so pointers are checked. But if I don't override hashCode, as it's based
    //on every property, the hashCode is calculated considering the content of the MutableList!
    //    override fun hashCode(): Int {
    //        return name.hashCode()
    //    }
    
    }
    
    data class Card(val name: String, val suite: String)
    
    class Game(val players: List<Player>) {
    
        val cardMap: MutableMap<Player, MutableList<Card>> = mutableMapOf()
    
        fun putIntoMapAndGiveCards() {
            val newCards = cardMap.getOrDefault(players[0], mutableListOf())
            newCards.add(Card(name = "Four", suite = "Clubs"))
            cardMap[players[0]] = newCards
    
            //This changes the default hashCode - I can use data classes in a list, but not in a map, because maps are
            //based on it.
            players[0].cards.add(Card(name = "Five", suite = "Clubs"))
        }
    
        fun getFromMap(): MutableList<Card>? {
            val player = players[0]
            assert(player != null, { "Player from list failure" })
    
            val indexOfPlayer = cardMap.keys.indexOf(player)
            assert(indexOfPlayer == 0, { "Player is in the map" })
    
            //Without overriding hashCode, cards is null!
            val cards = cardMap.get(players[0])
            assert(cards != null, { "Cards from map failure" })
            return cards
        }
    
    }
    
    
    fun main() {
        val player1 = Player(name = "John")
        val game = Game(mutableListOf(player1))
        game.putIntoMapAndGiveCards()
    
        game.getFromMap()
            ?: throw Exception( """Map.get() failure because Player is a data class.
            | A data class by default builds its hashCode with every property. As it contains a MutableList, 
            |   the hashCode changes when I add elements to the list. This means that I can't find the element using get()
        """.trimMargin())
    
        println("Test finished!")
    }
```

Comment: data classes do define an equals() method

Comment: by the way, instead of the second constructor in `Player` you could have just written `data class Player(val name: String, var cards: MutableList<Card> = mutableListOf())`. I believe this has identical behavior

Answer (score 6):

> By default, they define hashCode() based on every property of the class. But they don't define a default equals() method

This is not correct. Data classes generate both `equals()` and `hashCode()` consistently based on the properties declared in the data class's primary constructor (same goes for `toString()` btw).

Here is the decompiled code for `equals` and `hashCode` of your `Player` class:

```java
   public int hashCode() {
      String var10000 = this.name;
      int var1 = (var10000 != null ? var10000.hashCode() : 0) * 31;
      List var10001 = this.cards;
      return var1 + (var10001 != null ? var10001.hashCode() : 0);
   }

   public boolean equals(@Nullable Object var1) {
      if (this != var1) {
         if (var1 instanceof Player) {
            Player var2 = (Player)var1;
            if (Intrinsics.areEqual(this.name, var2.name) && Intrinsics.areEqual(this.cards, var2.cards)) {
               return true;
            }
         }

         return false;
      } else {
         return true;
      }
   }
```

Your problem is that you declare your `cards` mutable list in the primary constructor so it's part of the generated `equals` and `hashCode`.

The solution is to move this `cards` property to the body of your class instead (since it's not part of the player's "core data", but rather part of the state):

```kotlin
data class Player(val name: String) {
    val cards: MutableList<Card> = mutableListOf()
}
```

This way, the generated `equals`/`hashCode` pair will only be based on the `name` property.

Another option obviously is to override both `equals` and `hashCode` manually to take only the `name` into account, but that's tedious and not very idiomatic.

> I'm wondering if, due to the default behaviour, overriding hashCode() and equals() should be "mandatory" with data classes because otherwise using them with Maps can lead to errors.

I think you have misdiagnosed the default behaviour. So I'd say on the contrary overriding `equals`/`hashCode` is actually not very idiomatic for data classes, and should in general be avoided.

Using data classes is usually safe in maps, as long as the data in the primary constructor is not mutable.

---

#### Side notes

- you really should not mix `var` with mutable collections. It creates 2 ways of changing the collection, which is pretty unexpected and error-prone. You should instead either use a `val MutableList` or a `var List`, so you can only change the list via mutation, or only change it via assignment, but not both.
- if you want to insert the new value into the map, you shouldn't use `getOrDefault` + assign the value to the key. Instead, use `getOrPut` directly, so the default value will be inserted without extra work.
- why are you both using a `cards` property on the `Player` and a `Map<Player, List<Card>>`? Looks like you have 2 states that can change independently now because those card lists are independent.

Comment: Thank you, that explains a few things :)
>  as long as the data in the primary constructor is not mutable.
This is the key point I missed. The primary constructor parameters are a sort of primary key.

Comment: > why are you both using a cards property on the Player and a Map<Player, List<Card>>?
This is just an example I wrote to show the problem I had. The two sets of cards are independent. Player.cards represents the cards a player has in hand, while the map represents the cards he won in a specific Game that has this concept (other games don't) and it seems to me that Data classes can't be expanded. But it's just code to familiarize with Kotlin structures and semantics.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for clarifying then.